# What are the practical benefits of semantic markup for visual user-agents

Tags: html, semantic-markup

After years of creating HTML documents and trying to keep abreast of different markup patterns and best practices that make the markup the most meaningful I'm often left wondering how these semantics will start paying off for end-users.

Let's introduce the question as: **You have two documents…**

*The first document* uses all of the most reasonably standardized parts of contemporary HTML to create a rich document structure peppered with some RDFa and choice microfromats for an exemplary expressive piece of HTML.

*The second document* is the same structure as the first except that the tags have all been converted to divs and spans and all of the classnames are purely stylehooks: all semantics have been removed but the page renders efficiently and visually identical to the first.

**I'm interested in the direct benefits of the first document over the second document to a well-sighted human who is interacting with this HTML document via a desktop or mobile browser.** Your answer can invent the nature of the content and point at specific browser features to demonstrate your point.

Your answer should not include:

- Screen readers (the user is well-sighted)
- SEO (the indirect benefit of search engine visibility is off topic)
- Semantic markup is easier to maintain (which is also indirect)

Comment: I don't follow the last line. *Usually* good code is clean code which often is semantical code. So non-semantical coding is using `<div style>`, for everything as per doc2.

Comment: FF (and probably Chrome) has [extensions](http://microformats.org/wiki/firefox-extensions) that are capable of reading micro-formats (RDFA and microdata)

Comment: @RyanB Good point, my meaning was lost so I amended that point. All I meant was that the non-semantic code was not arbitrarily complex: it still renders efficiently, it simply lacks semantic value.

Comment: The question titles says "user-agents" although the question body restricts it to "browser[s]". Please adjust the title if you don't want to discuss other user-agents (than browsers and screen readers).

Comment: If all you care about is visual output, then `<table>`s are fine. However, we've moved away from table layouts precisely because of all the points you have declared off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is, of course, not complete. It's just what came to my mind while typing.)

This answer assumes: for users of desktop/mobile browsers without a screenreader; page consists of `div` and `span` elements only (with allowed attributes); only what is relevant today ([not tomorrow](http://nightly.mozilla.org/), [not in 2400 years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Now_Foundation)).

#### Missing metadata

- users won't see a favicon (`icon` link type; unless you place an ICO img in root) nor a title (`title` element) when bookmarking your page
- no icon when creating shortcut (`apple-touch-icon`, `msapplication-TileImage`, …)
- it will not be possible for certain web applications to extract metadata out of your pages when users post/quote/share your page there (e.g. [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/))
- browser won't auto-detect your feed (`alternate` link type)
- No (performance) benefits by link types like `prefetch`, `prerender`, `dns-prefetch`, `pingback`, `prev`/`next`, …

(Note that *some* of this could be accomplished with HTTP headers.)

#### Missing default functionality

Without `a`, `input`, `textarea`, `button` etc. the corresponding functionalites would require JavaScript. Users without JavaScript couldn't click at links, search, upload files, submit forms, …

Reasons for no (or limited) JS support:

- user deactivated JS (globally, for site/host only)

  - deliberately, e.g. with [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript)
  - required by company/admin/etc.
- JS files couldn't load (CDN issues, …)
- *very* old browser
- …

Also some typical navigation mechanisms might no be available by default (tabbing through fields; focus; pressing enter to activate; search in link text (e.g. `'` in Firefox)).

#### Missing functionality provided by browser extensions

There are *various* browser add-ons (or bookmarklets, etc.) that parse the markup and "do things".

- list all links ([Link Gopher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-gopher/), …)
- create a outline/toc (`h1`-`h6`) (e.g. [Table of Contents](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/table-of-contents/))
- only present the main content of the page (e.g. [Readability](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/readability/), …)
- process/sort/etc. tables (`table`) (e.g. [table calculator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/table-calculator/), …)
- extract metadata (e.g. [Dublin Core Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dublin-core-viewer/), …)
- microformats (e.g. [Operator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/operator/), …)
- RDF (RDFa, …) (e.g. [RDFa Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rdfa-developer/), [Semantic Radar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/semantic-radar/), [OpenLink Data Explorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/openlink-data-explorer/), …)
- Creative Commons (e.g. [OpenAttribute](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/openattribute/), …)
- …

#### Missing default "styling"

Without CSS support, a page consisting of only `div` and `span` elements may be hard to read, or it could even become unintelligible (think of complex data tables, for example).

Reasons for no (or limited) CSS support:

- text browsers ([Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29), [w3m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m), …)
- very old graphical browsers
- user deactivated CSS (globally, for site only, for page only)
- user uses own stylesheet
- CSS files couldn't load (CDN issues, …)
- …

#### Limited reusability

- copy & pasting: If users copy&paste some content and/or markup and your custom CSS doesn't get "included" (probably the case for many, many tools), it may be hard or even impossible to understand/reuse that content/markup.
- extracting your content: it's harder for others to scrape your content (e.g. [Piggy Bank](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Piggy_Bank)) and/or transform it (XSLT, XPath)

Comment: How I read the poster's question to be he would be using `p`, `a`, etc, he wouldn't be coding using the bells and whistles we have now. Essentiaally coding circa 1997/1998 vs now.

Comment: Though @RyanB is absolutely right about the intention of my question I think this answer smartly takes it at logical face value and shows how much baked-in functionality occurs as a result of basic semantic markup. Curious if there are use-cases beyond these basics but presently this answer is the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

For a well sighted user, there's probably no difference.

You should never assume the capabilities of a user, however.

Aside from accessibility, the biggest difference would be in how machines interpret the code. So, SEO matters, even though you want to rule that out as well. Browser extensions as mentioned elsewhere, and whatever might come in the future.

Comment: Are there any notable browser extensions presently?